# Is there third-party software for Canon tethered live-view shooting?

Tags: canon, software, tethering, live-view

I can use Canon EOS Utility to shoot tethered so that the live-view preview is displayed on the computer screen.

However, I would like to know if there is any *third-party software* (non-Canon) that supports Canon DSLRs and live-view shooting. I am using Mac, but feel free to suggest software for any platform.

(For example, Apple Aperture supports tethered shooting; however, it does not display the live-view preview.)

---

PS. Tip of the week: If you are using Mac OS X Lion + EOS Utility, do not upgrade it to the latest version. Older versions (2.8.1) seem to work somewhat ok on Lion; the latest version (2.10.2) simply refuses to start and displays the message "Cannot be used with this version of the operating system".

Comment: For those with Nikon/Mac: http://www.sofortbildapp.com/

Comment: Jukka - please add your comment to the body of the question and refer to specific version numbers so it stands the test of time.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are looking for third-party software? Something lacking from the Canon utility?

Comment: @mattdm: Well, I think my first comment is already a good enough reason – a recent software update that *removes* the support for the latest version of Mac OS X. :)

Comment: since you are looking for any platform, DSLR Controller is a very neat app on Android platoform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know [gPhoto](http://www.gphoto.org/) does this (free), i am just not sure if it's available to non linux environments.

Comment: The project page specifically mentions Linux. I could not find a definitive description of LiveView support on all EOS cameras (they do mention EOS 1000D but it is experimental). +1 anyway for the find.

Comment: it's possible it also works on a mac, but i have no way to test it :)

Comment: Carefully reading your answer again,I seem to have missed the "non" at the first time... My comment makes less sense now :-(

Answer (score 2):

Nothing I know of supports live-view. Capture One has an interesting feature called "composition mode" where you can shoot, but it doesn't save to the disk. Once you turn that off, the last shot (and all subsequent ones) are saved to the disk. While it's not the same as live view, it does work for me and allows me to avoid the Canon software (which is really bad, IMO).

Comment: EOSU is not *too* bad, really, but it is a good idea to thoroughly RTFM to learn all of its pitfalls and options. I learned that two weeks ago when preparing a presentation on portrait photography ay our club. It *could* be made more friendly, though.

Comment: Steve, I'm unfamiliar with Capture One (or any Apple software) but out of curiosity, what you suggest is that "composition mode" shoots remotely but only for preview purposes? That means that you shoot, then preview and correct, then shoot again, etc. until satisfied? If so, this looks like a tedious process.

Comment: Capture One is cross-platform Windows/Mac. You are right about how this works, but the process is not as tedious as it seems. I can do a certain amount of composition on the camera through the viewfinder or in LiveView. There really is no substitute on the computer for that. C1 then allows me to shoot test shots until I am happy with the way the exposure, lighting, color temperature, and all that work out. I may tweak some bits of the composition, but by and large, I'm working the preview of what I'll do in post. This is only for still life stuff. For models, I never would shoot this way.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a start on a similar piece of software. It uses libgphoto2, which appears to be available for Linux and Mac OS X.

You can download the program from: https://launchpad.net/liveview

Answer (score 1):

I use Helicon Remote (not free) which supports Windows,Mac and Android. It also allows bracketing and time-lapse. http://www.heliconsoft.com/software-downloads/

Comment: can you edit your answer and tell us more about it? Do you like it? What's good about it? What's bad about it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a software for windows (and possible mac as well) that has live view capability. Is called DSLR Remote Pro from breeze systems http://www.breezesys.com/DSLRRemotePro/

Comment: Welcome to photography.stackexchange.com. On the off chance that you are affilated with Breeze Sys we do ask that you disclose that. (Note, it is perfectly ok if you are!)