# Live view from my laptop

Tags: live-view, tethering

I am an intermediate photographer and I want to shoot some models in a cityscape. I want to frame my shots on my laptop and then shoot the image. How can I do this. Do I need any specific software? FYI, I'm shooting with a Canon 450D.

Answer (score 4):

The feature you're looking for is known as "tethering."  There is a lot of software support for tethered shooting, including Canon's own EOS utility and [others](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/15944/27832).

Answer (score 0):

Your camera should have come with some software, which is includes the EOS Utility. This software allows a canon camera to be connected, via USB to the computer. Live view is possible. With the camera on and connected to the computer, the program will automatically detect the connection.

Features include:

- ability to save to camera and computer
- live view
- ability to control exposure etc.
- interval shooting

Answer (score 0):

You could use Adobe lightroom for tethering. Supporter cameras https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support-lightroom-4.html

Comment: Please explain how to use Lightroom for tethering, and advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @damnedtruths https://photographylife.com/mastering-lightroom-how-to-tether-your-camera

Comment: All information that helps to answer the question should be in the main body, not comments. Also, please include a summary of the link as well (you don't need it for the first link because it is a list)