# Options for streaming shots back to laptop / ipad during shoot

Tags: canon, tethering, preview, wifi-sd

I'm looking into the different options for streaming shots back to a laptop or iPad as they are shot on from a Canon D6.

So far the options I've come across are :

- Cam ranger, seems quite expensive, and has features such as being able to change the shot settings remotely which i don't really need, just looking for shots to be fed back so others on shoot can see the photos and suggest amendments / changes while we are still shooting that scene.
- EyeFi - Couldn't quite make my mind up on this has any one had any experience ? I've read some horror stories, where people have shot all day, and when although the data syncs to the iPad, when they viewed the memory card at the end of the day the photo hadn't been saved.
- Is there a wired system were i can run a lead to my laptop ? If so is there a special lead and software required ?

Are there any other preferable solutions from the list above, or are there any solutions i might have missed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there third-party software for Canon tethered live-view shooting?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15944/is-there-third-party-software-for-canon-tethered-live-view-shooting)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called **tethered shooting**. With a laptop or a USB OTG enabled Android device, you need nothing more than a USB cable and some (free) software. E.g. Canon's EOS utility, or Lightroom, on the computer.

With the iPad, you are out of luck in this regard, AFAIK, apart from your mentioned EyeFi solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of Eye-Fi's....Pumped 10,000+ pics through the main one (jpg/RAW/video), with nary a burp, from a Fuji HS-10. Never done it to an iPad though...just directly to the main PC or laptop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the 6D, it has built-in Wi-Fi and Canon has free tethering software for both computers and mobile devices.

http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/cameraconnect_app_features

http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/EOS_app

http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/eos_utility

These are Canon USA links but the software is available in other countries as well.